# JSP get/setParameter with whole Objects

Tags: jsp

Im very new in this community and come up with my first question.

Im using JSP an i successfully created JSP-Sites which were using 
jsp:setParameter and jsp:getParameter with single Strings.

Now i want to do the same with whole Objects (Yes i know string is an object too :P). 
I tried the following:

This is my Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_SPJ_MOVIE")
public class Movie implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="MOVIE_ID", unique=true)
    private int movieID = 0;

    @Column(name="MOVIE_BACKDROPPATH")
    private String backDropPath = "";

    @Column(name="MOVIE_ORIGINALTITLE")
    private String originalTitle = "";

    @Column(name="MOVIE_POPULARITY")
    private double popularity = 0.0;

    @Column(name="MOVIE_POSTERPATH", length=1000)
    private String posterPath = "";

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="MOVIE_RELEASEDATE")
    private Date releaseDate = null;

    @Column(name="MOVIE_TITLE")
    private String title = "";

    @Column(name="MOVIE_ADULT")
    private boolean adult = false;

    @Column(name="MOVIE_BUDGET")
    private int budget = 0;

    @Column(name="MOVIE_HOMEPAGE", length=1000)
    private String homepage = "";

    @Lob
    @Column(name="MOVIE_OVERVIEW", length=1000)
    private String overview = "";

    @Column(name="MOVIE_RUNTIME")
    private int runtime = 0;

    @Column(name="MOVIE_VOTEAVERAGE")
    private double voteAverage = 0.0;

    @Column(name="MOVIE_VOTECOUNT")
    private int voteCount = 0;

    public Movie() {}

    //##########################################################################################
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transient
    public List<Movie> getMovies() {
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SPJUnit");
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Movie m");

        movies = (List<Movie>)query.getResultList();

        return movies;
    }
    @Transient
    private Movie currentMovie = null;
    public Movie getCurrentMovie() {
            return currentMovie;
    }
    public void setCurrentMovie(Movie currentMovie) {
        this.currentMovie = currentMovie;
    }
    //##########################################################################################

    // Getter and Setter 

    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

This is my movies.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="movie" class="de.Movie"></jsp:useBean>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<head>
    <link href="../css/movies.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Movie Titles</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <br></br>
    <h2 id="title">Movie Titles</h2>
    <br></br>

    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="movie" items="${movie.movies}">
            <li id="listElement">
                <form action="../pages/singleMovie.jsp">
                    <input type="submit" 
                           name="currentMovie" 
                           value="${movie}"
                    />
                </form>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here i have a big list of all Movies. i think because of my toString() method
all titles are printed out right? Well with these forms i want to submit the selected movie to another jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="movie" class="de.Movie"></jsp:useBean>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<head>
    <link href="../css/singleMovie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Movie</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <jsp:setProperty name="movie" property="*" />

    <br></br>
    <h2 id="title"><jsp:getProperty name="movie" property="currentMovie" /></h2>
    <br></br>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that there just the title of the movie was sent because i get the following error when i call the singleMovie.jsp:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException:  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6338: Cannot convert "Ariel" for the attribute currentMovie of the bean de.Movie: PWC6348: Property editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager
```

"Ariel" is the title of the movie i selected to submit.

I want to send the whole Movie so i can use all fields of the Movie-Bean in my
singleMovie.jsp.

As long as i just worked with the titles of the movies everything worked great.

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to realize that HTML and HTTP don't work with objects. They can only submit string parameters.

You should not build an app with JSPs only. JSPs are great to generate HTML. The rest (getting parameters, validating them, retrieving and saving objects from/to the database, etc.) should be done using Java code, in a servlet, or in a controller of your preferred MVC framework.

You also shouldn't have to send a whole movie to the server to display it. The movie is in the database, at server-side. All the server needs to get from the client is the ID of the movie it must display. So the app should work like this:

1. A request is sent to the ListMovies servlet
2. The servlet searches the movies in the database, and stores the list of movies in a request attribute
3. The servlet forwards to the listMovies.jsp
4. The listMovies use the JSTL and the EL to iterate through the movies stored in the request attribute, and, for each of them, generates a link to `displayMovie?id=theMovieId`. DOn't use a form containing just a button when a link should be used.
5. The user clicks on the link. A request is sent to the DisplayMovie servlet
6. The servlet gets the value of the `id` parameter. It finds the movie in the database using this ID, and stores it in a request attribute
7. The servlet forwards to the displayMovie.jsp page
8. The displayMovie.jsp page uses the JSTL and the EL to display the details of the movie

Forget completely about jsp:useBean, jsp:setProperty and jsp:getProperty. They belong to the past, and shouldn't be used anymore.

Also, the methods to execute queries against the database to get movies shouldn't be in the Movie class. They should be in a `MovieDAO` class. It doesn't make much sense to instantiate a movie just to get other movies from the database. And an Entity's responsibility is not to query the database.